# Expanding rows into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, windows

I'm trying to create a pivot table and am running into some problems getting the output.  I'm package agnostic, I've tried reshape2, tidry and dplyr and haven't gotten anything to work.

My attempts so far have all error'd out, I also managed to gather the data to remove the Fill and Target into a new variable called "Type" and the value is "Seats...but that doesn't seem to help either.

`mynewdf = gather(mydf,Type,Seats,c("Fill","Target"))`

Code that I think is close to working.....

`t=dcast(mydf, Date + Type + Month ~ Seats, length, drop=FALSE)`

My current data structure looks like:

```
Date Month Fill Target Code
1234  Jan  14    15    13B
1234  Feb  12    14    13B
.................
1235  Oct  13    16    13F
```

There should never be any duplicate Date/Month/Code and what I want to display ultimately is the Fill and Target (eventually doing some calculated fields but I'll cross that bridge later).

I would like the output to be:

```
        Jan             Feb        .......   Oct .....    
Date Fill  Target  Fill  Target    ....... Fill Target.... MOS
1234  14    15     12     14       ....................... 13B
1235  ......................................13   16  ..... 13F
```

I tried grouping by Month and Fill then also Month and Target but had no luck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You should also include the code of your attempt to solve this problem in order for us to help you.

Comment: I added some code I'm working on....everything just errors out.

Comment: Please add a sample set of ur data.`dput(df)` should help with that

Comment: This package will help to produce the kind of multi-level grouping you're looking for:   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pivottabler/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a bit more verbose than I would like, but this should give you a start.

First enter the data frame as you've shown it:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

mydf <- data.frame(Date = c(1234, 1234, 1235),
                   Month = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Oct'),
                   Fill = c(14, 12, 13),
                   Target = c(15, 14, 16),
                   Code = c('13B', '13B', '13F'))
```

Then start data wrangling with `tidyr::unite()`:

```
> newdf <- mydf %>% 
+     tidyr::unite(Fill_Target, Fill, Target, sep='_')
> newdf
  Date Month Fill_Target Code
1 1234   Jan       14_15  13B
2 1234   Feb       12_14  13B
3 1235   Oct       13_16  13F
```

So you are combining the Fill and Target variables into a single column. Doing this, you can then use `tidyr::spread`:

```
> newdf <- newdf %>% tidyr::spread(Month, Fill_Target)
> newdf
  Date Code   Feb   Jan   Oct
1 1234  13B 12_14 14_15  <NA>
2 1235  13F  <NA>  <NA> 13_16
```

So here then you have Date, and Code, and then your Month followed by the Fill_Target values.  Then use `tidyr::separate()` to separate these into individual columns:

```
> newdf <- newdf %>% 
+     tidyr::separate(Jan, into = c('Jan_Fill', 'Jan_Target')) %>% 
+     tidyr::separate(Feb, into = c('Feb_Fill', 'Feb_Target')) %>% 
+     tidyr::separate(Oct, into = c('Oct_Fill', 'Oct_Target'))
> newdf
  Date Code Feb_Fill Feb_Target Jan_Fill Jan_Target Oct_Fill Oct_Target
1 1234  13B       12         14       14         15     <NA>       <NA>
2 1235  13F     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>       <NA>       13         16
```

Then you can use `dplyr::select()` to reorder the columns

```
> newdf %>% 
+   select(Date, Jan_Fill, Jan_Target, Feb_Fill, Feb_Target, Oct_Fill, Oct_Target, 
+          Code)
  Date Jan_Fill Jan_Target Feb_Fill Feb_Target Oct_Fill Oct_Target Code
1 1234       14         15       12         14     <NA>       <NA>  13B
2 1235     <NA>       <NA>     <NA>       <NA>       13         16  13F
```

Now, I don't love this answer because it's a bit verbose, especially when you consider you're going to have 12 months.  But it might be easier/better for you to be a bit verbose and deliberate in your code rather than mess with quasiquotations and trying to separate and select months in a fancier way.

Also, I note that there is only a single row of "header" as opposed to your two rows. Unfortunately, if you want a second header row, you'll have to use Python Pandas; R does not support this.

Comment: It does take some extra work but I was able to get it....:       mydf=mydf %>% unite(Fill_Target,Fill,Target,sep="_") %>% spread(Month,Fill_Target) %>% 
      separate(JAN, into =c("JANFill","JANTarget")) ...etc and separate all 12 months!